# Least decimal places rule produces ridiculous results

Tags: error-analysis

The rule I learnt from my physics teacher and textbook in adding numbers together was that the end result must be rounded to the least number of decimal points in the starting numbers.

This makes sense for say $ 12.4 + 0.03 = 12.4$ because the additional $0.03$ would be too uncertain.

But this rule leads to very ridiculous things. A physics teacher cannot reasonably say "well the universe is 13.7 billion and 3 years old - because when I started teaching 3 years ago, the universe was 13.7 billion years old and thus it must now be 13.7 billion and 3 years old".

This seems unreasonable. Using significant figures here would seem to solve the problem nicely.

How do I go about using this least decimal place rule without looking ridiculous?

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? How should I improve the question?

Comment: Your title is a - highly questionable - statement, not a question.

Comment: You have to use the same scale to use this rule. That is 13.7 billion + 0.000003 billion years, is 13.7 billion years. That is, the least significant figure in 13.7 billion is the 7, and that is far to the left of the least significant figure in 3. You can think of this as 13.7 having negative decimal points, if you like, but it makes more sense if you say "significant figure".

Answer (score 1):

I generally disapprove of that rule. It drastically oversimplifies things, e.g. you may know a number exactly (say c = 1 in natural units), but wouldn't then start rounding everything to 1 significant digit because one of the inputs had only 1 significant digit.

A much better way to think is in terms of probability distributions over the values. E.g. you may approximate the values you know to be distributed normally with mean x, and std. Δx. Then you can reframe the statment in that the mean age will have changed by exactly 3 years, but the std will not have changed significantly (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

Comment: Zero is a significant digit.  Let's say I measure a displacement, $d$. If I say $d=12.000\text{mm}$, that's different from me saying $d=12\text{mm}$. In the first case, you may assume that I meant $d=12\text{mm}\pm0.0005\text{mm}$, but in the second case, you must assume that I could have meant $d=12\text{mm}\pm0.5\text{mm}$.

Comment: If I _define_ $c$ to be _exactly_ 1, Then I can put however many "significant" zeros after the decimal point as I need.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is not faulty. Rather, it is considered acceptably inaccurate. A notation x=12.4 implies $12.35 \leq x \lt 12.45$. Adding 0.03 leads to $12.38 \leq x \lt 12.48$. This notation may be seen as awkward so the less accurate solution is to drop the 0.03.